# Craftsman Garden Tractor 26 HP no Drive when I let the clutch out

Tags: lawnmower, craftsman, drive-belt

Craftman 26 HP Electric Start 6 Speed Transaxle Model 917.25024. my problem is very simular first mow of the season.  mowed about 15 ft. and stopped to check how it was mowing and when i went to let the clutch out  nothing there.  the difference that I can see is the engine drive pully is not moving. Nothing with the Clutch  or gears.Drive belt seems tight. cleaned the  clutch plate as my book says is one step.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Maybe the drive pully is slipping on the crankshaft?